# Get SKUs information from Google Cloud Billing API in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api, google-cloud-billing

In Google CLoud, it's possible to export some pricing data from Cloud Billing to BigQuery... The structure of this pricing data export is displayed [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/pricing-data?hl=en).
Among other things, there are some information regarding the "list of product categories that apply to the SKU" in a column called `product_taxonomy`.

```
| product_taxonomy | Array of Strings | List of product categories that apply to the SKU, such as Serverless, Cloud Run, TaskQueue, VMs On Demand, Cores: Per Core, and others.
```

But, in the billing API, there are other information regarding the SKUs that seems to be more detailed and easier to understand ["Getting the list of SKUs for a service"](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api?hl=en#getting_the_list_of_skus_for_a_service)

Especially in the key category:

```
    "category": {
        "serviceDisplayName": "[SVC_DISPLAY_NAME]",
        "resourceFamily": "[FAMILY]",
        "resourceGroup": "[GROUP]",
        "usageType": "[USAGE]",
    },
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to get the "SKU category" data directly in the "pricing data export" exported to BQ?
2. Otherwise, what you be a good, eazy-to-maintain solution to fetch those data from the API in a BQ dataset so I can merge them with the "pricing data export"? [This article](https://philhather.medium.com/loading-api-data-into-google-bigquery-with-cloud-functions-and-scheduler-ffc4a74b2e05) proposes a method using Cloud Functions & Cloud Scheduler but I was wondering if there wasn't a more elegant solution?